# New Hard Drive is missing - was present in Bios not in Windows 8 Administrative storage

Tags: windows-8

I have a HP dV7t-7000 laptop with windows 8. I added a second HDD which gets detected in the BIOS, but not in windows 8. Both drives are 1TB in size.

Comment: Does the HDD have a filesystem?  What are you using to verify Windows can see the disk?  If it has no filesystem there are other tools you can use to make it appears in `My Computer`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a brand new drive, it might have to be initialized in Disk Management.

In Windows 8, open Run from the Apps screen and type `diskmgmt.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should see the hard drive in the bottom pane.  Select it and click `Initialize` and format it as necessary.